# Twostep cluster spss show a column with cluster number

Tags: spss

In spss I run the `twostep` cluster.

In the output console I can see the graph which shows the clusters.

How is it possible to create a new column in the dataset and show the number of cluster every row belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your syntax command you should add a `save cluster` sub-command. For example:

```
TWOSTEP CLUSTER
.
.
.
/SAVE CLUSTER VARIABLE = ClusterNum.
```

This will run the analysis and save the cluster number in a new variable called `ClusterNum`.